# Where is the mod folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I've downloaded Minecraft Forge for Minecraft v1.6.4 and I can't find the mods folder! Where do I look? I've looked in my Forge folder but it wasn't there!

Answer (score 9):

You can find your Mod folder here:

```
C:\Users\\[username]\AppData\Roaming\\.minecraft\mods
```

.. and [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Installing_Mods) is a useful resource that covers some more of the basics:

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a Mac, your mods folder should be located at:

```
~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/mods
```

Simply use <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in Finder to openup the *Go to the folder...* window. Enter the path above in there and press *Go*. You should now be in your mods folder.

Answer (score 1):

Go in start and type `%appdata%` and then click on .minecraft from roaming.

Comment: The video is irrelevant to finding the mods folder, so I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

When you get forge you first have to launch forge t=in the minecraft launcher when you at the minecraft main screen, after that go to your start for windows xp-7 and for windows 8 put your courser on the top right or bottom right coner then search %appdata% then click on .minecraft and your mod folder is there