# Where is the Mods folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I've downloaded Minecraft Forge for Minecraft v1.11.2 and I can't find the mods folder! Where do I look? I've looked in my %appdata% and clicked on .Minecraft and no Mods folder!

Comment: Please someone help!

Comment: I don't have a PC so I'm no pro at this, but I heard if you're in your Minecraft folder you can create one and name it 'mods' if you don't see one already.

Comment: Related questions: [Where is the mod folder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/151317/145980), [Mods folder isn't in .minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/248478/145980), [How exactly do I install Minecraft mods and what is Forge?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/164341/145980)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the mod folder has to be created by you, by creating a folder and naming it "mods"

Comment: This is correct, it has to be created by the user.